# The most effective way to use interp1 command in matlab with two columns

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two columns (same size) that I have to interpolate in Matlab. First column is a vector of time in hours (9.5, 9.6 9.73 10.13 etc...) and the other column are stock prices associated to each element of the column "time in hours".

I wish to have some prices that are associated with each 15min, 30min, 45min, and 1hour (60min) that are missing in my price vector. And therefore, thee elements (15,30,45min and 60min) are also missing in my column of time per hours.

How can I linearly interpolate two columns in order to have the same size and then be able to associate a price at every 15min (X.25hour, X.5hour, X.75hour and X hour)?

Thank you!

Comment: Note, that linear interpolation is not causal. In order to fill missing points it uses the information from future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a one line command:

```
interp_prices = interp1(time, prices, 0:0.25:max(time));
```

Comment: ah superb! Would you know if I can run the interp1 command by day? By that I mean, in addition to my column time and prices I have days and I don't want to interpolate between days... that is between say 16.5hours (calculated from midnight) to 9hours (am). Thanks again!

Comment: For that I suggest multiplying the number of days you want it for by 7.5, and putting that at the end of 0:0.25:___. Then split the interpolated results you get by chunks of 7.5 hours.

Comment: thanks! good idea or I might simply run interp1 and then delete the rows that fit between the hours that I don't want. I hoping for a faster way since I am dealing with 20million observations already and I want to avoid creating much more data and then having another step to delete. Thanks again Ansari!

Comment: No you don't want to delete the rows between the non-working hours because you want your interpolation to jump from 4:30 PM one day to 9 AM the next day - you simply don't want to interpolate at the time points in between. You're welcome :)